# Does permutation exist

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I am trying to figure out the proper query in linq to sql, but I just cant figure out how to do so. Lets say I have a table with the following (this table basically is a one to many relationship)

```
Id (PK) | SupervisorId | EmployeeId
    1          1            5
    2          1            6
    3          1            7
    4          2            5
    5          2            6
    6          3            7
    7          4            7
    8          4            8
```

I want my linq to sql query to find the supervisorId which has for employeeId 5 and 6. The query would return 2 only. I could use 2 where clause, but lets say I would want to input 3 employeeIds, my query would have to modified. If the passed permutation doesnt exist for one matched SupervisorId (ex: 5,6,8 in this case), the result would be null or empty.

The function would look like this:

```
int FindSuperVisorId(List<int> employeeIds);
```

I really dont know where to start in linq to sql for this type of scenario.

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to happen if the employeeIds passed in don't have the same SupervisorId, e.g. you pass in employee IDs 5,7,8?

Comment: And I think that your method could return more than one results, for example supervisors having 5 and 6 for employeeId are 1 and 2, and not only 2.

Comment: You're wanting to perform "relational division" - I'm not sure how easy that is to express in Linq to SQL.

Comment: @Tawnos I added precision in my question. So if the supervisorId isnt the same, basically there is no result

Comment: @polkduran Preferably I would prefer that the results match exactly the number of input ids. In this case, 1 would be ignored since it has 3 items instead of 2.

Comment: ah ok I get it, you mean 'exactly' having these employeeId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm pretty sure that this query should be converted property to LINQ to SQL, but I'm not completely sure.

So first we group by supervisor so that we have sequences of employees for that supervisor.  Then we use `Except` with the employees you're interested in in both directions.  If the the count of both of those `Except` calls is zero then the sets are exactly equal.  There are more efficient ways of determining if two sets are equal in linq-to-objects, but I doubt they would be properly converted to SQL code.

```
var supervisorId = table.GroupBy(item => item.SupervisorId)
    .Select(group => new
    {
        additionalItems = group.Select(item => item.EmployeeId).Except(employees),
        missingItems = employees.Except(group.Select(item => item.EmployeeId)),
        group = group
    })
    .Where(queries => queries.additionalItems.Count() == 0
    && queries.missingItems.Count() == 0)
    .Select(queries => queries.group.Key)//gets the supervisorID
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Servy, can you breakdown the explanation ? Im slightly confused, but this seems to be heading where Im looking for.

Comment: @guiomie What aspects of the query is giving you problems?  Do you understand each of the components as a whole, but not why putting them together works, or do you not understand the individual LINQ operations?

Comment: I think my main issue is understanding how to interface this logic with a DataContext

Comment: @guiomie Well, all you need is to have an IQueryable of an object with all of the fields of the table you mentioned in your question and that should be good enough.

Comment: Here is how I implemented with a DataContext: 

myContext.SupervisorEmployees.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(item => ...

Comment: @guiomie That means you're doing the entire operation on the client and pulling down the entire DB table.  If that's fine, then okay, but if the list is large, that may not be acceptable long term.

Comment: It works. I was submitting the wrong employeeIds, I hadnt refreshed my database view in MSSQL Server Management. How could I not pull down the whole DB ?

Comment: @guiomie Well, if the IDs of the employees you're using to search for the supervisor of was instead the results of a DB query instead of an in-memory list then the query would work just fine.  Is writing such a query possible?  If not, could you put the data into a temporary list and query that?

Comment: I just did this, swapped "myContext.SupervisorEmployees.AsEnumerable()" for "myContext.SupervisorEmployees.Where(i => employees.Contains(i.employeeId)).ToList())"  ...

Comment: If I send permutation 6-7 I receive a positive response, even tho this permutation only exists at 5-6-7 and not 6-7. Is this normal?

Comment: @guiomie That's because you're using an entirely different query than the one that I proposed.

Answer (score 1):

I had to model your table as a many-many relationship as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee](
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Employee] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SupervisorEmployees](
    [SupervisorId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [EmployeeId] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_SupervisorEmployees] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [SupervisorId] ASC,
    [EmployeeId] ASC
)
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SupervisorEmployees]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_SupervisorEmployees_Employee] FOREIGN KEY([SupervisorId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Employee] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SupervisorEmployees] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_SupervisorEmployees_Employee]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SupervisorEmployees]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_SupervisorEmployees_Employee1] FOREIGN KEY([EmployeeId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Employee] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SupervisorEmployees] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_SupervisorEmployees_Employee1]
GO
```

Then using Entity Framework database first (not Linq to SQL unfortunately) the following LINQPad code works fine:

```
void Main()
{
    FindSupervisorIds( new List<int>{5,6} ).Dump();
}

IEnumerable<int> FindSupervisorIds(List<int> employeeIds)
{
    // two Excepts to do 'sequence equals'
    var supervisors = Employees.Where (e =>
        !e.Employees.Select (em => em.Id).Except(employeeIds).Any()
        && !employeeIds.Except(e.Employees.Select (em => em.Id)).Any() 
    );

    return supervisors.Select (s => s.Id).Distinct();
}

int? FindSupervisorId(List<int> employeeIds)
{
    var supervisors = FindSupervisorIds(employeeIds).ToList();

    if(supervisors.Count == 1)
    {
        return supervisors.First ();
    }

    return null;
}
```

FindSupervisorIds generates a single SQL query.  If you need to check there's only one matching supervisor it's probably best to call ToList() on the returned list of supervisors as in FindSupervisorId.

Trying to do the same thing with LINQ to SQL fails due to the calls to Except with the exception
**'NotSupportedException: Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator.'**

Comment: This would return supervisor 1 for employees 5 and 6, it should return 2.

Comment: This will do the whole thing via Linq to objects, not Linq to SQL.

Comment: You're so picky :) What about this?  Not LinqToSql but it is EF.

Comment: Well, now it's very similar to my solution, barring a handful of mostly minor changes.  Your `FindSupervisorId` method should probably just use `supervisors.FirstOrDefault()` to both avoid fetching all of the additional items, and just to clean up the code.  That's about the only non-styalistic difference between our answers.

Comment: Well I enjoyed working it out for myself.  If you use FirstOrDefault() you'll get an exception if there's more than one matching supervisor.

Comment: No you won't, that would only be true of `Single` or `SingleOrDefault`.  `FirstOrDefault` will return the first item if there are multiple matches, and the default value (in this case, `null`) if there are none.

Answer (score 0):

one possibility:

```
public int FindSuperVisorId(IEnumerable<Employee> employes)
{
    var distinctSupervisors = employes.Select(e => e.SuperVisor).Distinct();
    var superVisor = distinctSupervisors.Where(supervisor => employes.All(employee => employee.SuperVisor.Equals(supervisor))).FirstOrDefault();
    return superVisor;
}
```

and in case you want all matches of same supervisors:

```
public IEnumerable<int> FindSuperVisorId(IEnumerable<Employee> employes)
{
    var distinctSupervisors = employes.Select(e => e.SuperVisor).Distinct();
    var equalSupervisors = distinctSupervisors .Where(supervisor => employes.All(employee => employee.SuperVisor.Equals(supervisor)));
    return equalSupervisors;
}
```

or directly:

```
public IEnumerable<int> FindSuperVisorId(IEnumerable<Employee> employes)
{
    return employes.Select(e => e.SuperVisor).Distinct()
        .Where(supervisor => employes.All(employee => employee.SuperVisor.Equals(supervisor)));
}
```

Comment: Im confused as how to pass "employes" if I have a db DataContext. I know the ids of those employes, but I dont have them as objects. I simply instantiate them or query them?